# How to solve the infinite time complexity problem shown below

Tags: time, complexity-theory, infinite

> 90 Kilograms of rocket fuel is necessary to propel 100 Kilograms of
> mass into Earth's orbit from sea level. However, this becomes tricky
> as, now the mass of the rocket is (100 + 90) = 190 Kilograms,
> inclusive of the original mass and the mass of the required fuel. This
> would now mean that we need an additional 81 KG of fuel to send the
> extra weight of the required fuel. Thus requiring 271 KG of total
> mass.

And the problem goes on and on forever, where we need to add additional fuel for the additional mass of the additional fuel. Seems like a O (∞) problem.

I am confused as to how to design a O(1) constant time algorithm to compute the rocket mass inorder to send M kg of mass. Also please let me know if there are other examples of O (∞).

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a math problem than it is a question about asymptotic notation.

Specifically, the math works out like this. You have an initial mass of m that you want to launch. You need to add .9m mass of fuel to move that to space. But that fuel itself requires .9(.9m) = (0.9)<sup>2</sup>m additional fuel, and that (0.9)<sup>2</sup>m fuel requires (0.9)<sup>3</sup>m additional fuel, etc. You therefore need to compute the quantity

> m + 0.9m + (0.9)<sup>2</sup>m + (0.9)<sup>3</sup>m + (0.9)<sup>4</sup>m + …
>
> = m · ((0.9)<sup>0</sup> + (0.9)<sup>1</sup> + (0.9)<sup>2</sup> + (0.9)<sup>3</sup> + (0.9)<sup>4</sup> + …)

That bit in parentheses is the sum of an infinite geometric series. You can show via a variety of techniques (do a quick Google search for a few examples) that the sum works out to

> 1 / (1 - 0.9) = 1 / 0.1 = 10,

and so the total mass of the rocket will be 10m, of which 9m is fuel.

Comment: Any other example similar to this ?

Comment: Geometric series like these arise in many other contexts. If you do some searching online you'll find a bunch of other applications.